# replaceWith with jQuery Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-manipulation, replacewith

I'm trying to use replaceWith(...) function with a jQuery Object but it does not work, when i try do it with inserted DOM elements it works, but not in jQuery objects.

I have this:

```
var obj = $('<div id="obj">Text</div>');
obj.replaceWith('<span>New text</span>');
```

**"obj" is not replaced with the new HTML.**

Here is the demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/v7EA2/

Maybe i did not understand how replaceWith() function works,

Thanks by your help.

---

**UPDATE**

Please look at here: http://jsfiddle.net/v7EA2/6/

Comment: If you are trying to replace and element in the DOM with another, you must select it first and then call .replaceWith() . In your example, you are creating a new element that does not exist in the DOM. Explain what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: Please tell us expected result!

Comment: I'm trying replace an element before insert it on DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `replace` it before `appending` into the `dom` by the following code,

```
  var obj = $('<div>Text</div>').not('div').add('<span>New text</span>');
```

Theory : First you have to exclude the `div` from the intial `Jquery object` and then you have to `add` the new set of html into it.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/v7EA2/11/)

Comment: Well, seems there is a bug in newer jQuery versions with replaceWith(...) function, but your answer despite of not be more elegant or intuitive, works for me now.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but how is this different from simply updating the variable with `obj = $('<span>New text</span>')`? Seems overkill to me.

Answer (score 4):

It happens because your element does not have a parent. Append it to the DOM or to another jQuery collection and it will work.

I created a [little demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sTcz2/) that might help in understanding what this method does.

**DETAILS:**

I will sum up the research that is detailed in the comments below this answer. Thanks to PSL, calberts, Jason P and A. Wolff.

1. The [documentation of `replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) states the following:

   > As of jQuery 1.4, .replaceWith() can also work on disconnected DOM
   >   nodes. For example, with the following code, .replaceWith() returns a
   >   jQuery set containing only a paragraph.:
   >
   > `$( "<div/>" ).replaceWith("<p></p>" );`
2. This means that the example provided by the OP should indeed work. [And it works till version 1.8](http://jsfiddle.net/my89M/9/). Unfortunately, [from version 1.9 it stops working](http://jsfiddle.net/my89M/10/). This seemed to be a bug and only happens if you are trying to replace the "root element" of the jQuery object.
3. Actually [the change in 1.9 was documented](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#after-before-and-replacewith-with-disconnected-nodes):

   > Prior to 1.9, .after(), .before(), and .replaceWith() would attempt to
   >   add or change nodes in the current jQuery set if the first node in the
   >   set was not connected to a document, and in those cases return a new
   >   jQuery set rather than the original set. This created several
   >   inconsistencies and outright bugs--the method might or might not
   >   return a new result depending on its arguments! As of 1.9, these
   >   methods always return the original unmodified set and attempting to
   >   use .after(), .before(), or .replaceWith() on a node without a parent
   >   has no effect--that is, neither the set or the nodes it contains are
   >   changed.

   Problem is that the change never made it to the official docs. I found [a bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13338) posted about this, but it was closed because it belongs to a different tracker.

---

Quick Solution:

In the OP's situation, the easiest way to "replace" the element would be

```
var obj = $('<div id="obj">Text</div>');
obj = $('<span>New text</span>');
```

but only if it is not in the DOM yet :).

Comment: Actually [doc says](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) `As of jQuery 1.4, .replaceWith() can also work on disconnected DOM nodes. For example, with the following code, .replaceWith() returns a jQuery set containing only a paragraph.:` `$( "<div/>" ).replaceWith( "<p></p>" );`

Comment: @PSL That is true, but the `obj` variable will still store the div, unless you update it with the return value of the `replaceWith` method.

Comment: No that doesn't work either, seems like a bug to me... Even according to the example provided in the doc it should work. Yeah try other way around as well. It doesn't

Comment: @PSL It is not a bug. The docs never state that the variable will be updated. Only the return value will be the new element.

Comment: But see this: http://jsfiddle.net/v7EA2/6/
If i try selecting something inside element, it works!!

Comment: `$( "<div/>" ).replaceWith( "<p></p>" );` should return a `p` tag but it doesnt

Comment: @:kapa But looking at the example provided by @calbertts, it works but not on root nodes. So considering the documentation this seems like a bug.

Comment: @PSL These two statements in the docs seem contradictory: _"The .replaceWith() method, like most jQuery methods, returns the jQuery object so that other methods can be chained onto it. However, it must be noted that the original jQuery object is returned. This object refers to the element that has been removed from the DOM, not the new element that has replaced it._" and _"As of jQuery 1.4, .replaceWith() can also work on disconnected DOM nodes. For example, with the following code, .replaceWith() returns a jQuery set containing only a paragraph.:"_ `$( "<div/>" ).replaceWith( "<p></p>" );`

Comment: @JasonP Yeah seems like it... :) Even the example they provided doesn't work.

Comment: @PSL the sample they provide works if we are talking about the same: http://jsfiddle.net/my89M/  See there, works too: http://jsfiddle.net/my89M/3/

Comment: @A.Wolff Something must have happened between 1.8 and 1.9 to change/break this: http://jsfiddle.net/cxxjZ/

Comment: @PSL my bad, ya so we can assume it is a bug

Comment: Will you report this like a bug?

Comment: @calbertts I made some further research and updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Jsfillde: http://jsfiddle.net/v7EA2/3/

first make the DOM available and then change the html using `$.replaceWith`

```
var obj = $('<div>Text</div>');
$('#result').text(obj[0].outerHTML);
$('#result').replaceWith('<span>Text</span>');
```